# XAML - displaying Image through string path

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a List<>vehicleList containing many properties one which includes the string pathway to the images folder containing the image to that vehicles image. I want to display the image in my main XAML by using the string path

The path look like this (selectedVehicle.VehImage):

```
F:\Legends\Sem 2\FOOP\FOOPAssignment\FOOPAssignment\images\Mondeo
```

The XAML image:

```
<Image x:Name="image_Vehicle" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="134" Margin="150.4,381,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190"/>
```

code:

```
image_Vehicle.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(selectedVehicle.VehImage.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path doesn't look like a relative path. Try using absolute.

Change `UriKind.Relative` to `UriKind.Absolute`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Works perfectly, whats the difference between the 2?

Comment: Relative means it's relative to your files current location. i.e. your xaml resides in the image folder and you need to call an image called img1 (also inside image folder). You can just call it like 'img1.jpg' , while Absolute is a complete reference.